# Create linkedserver for MSAccess Database ODBS DSN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, odbc

I have Ms Access database and I have configured an ODBC DSN for Ms Access Database. Now I want to create a **linkedserver** that connect to Ms Access DSN and fetches data from that. I have created linkedserver for MSSQL and MySQL ODBC DSN. So is there any way to do for Ms Access DSN?

Answer (score 1):

Click odbc database
then link to the data source by creating...
Choose machine data source
then new

Comment: thanks @pEte wEntz Mendoza for your reply. I was not able to understand you. Can u explain procedure step by step?